# How to Hide Products from Opencart Category by IDs?

Tags: opencart

I have a website in Opencart. We have a few hundred products on our store that we are trying to get ranked for SEO purposes (or search), but we only want their base products to be shown on the category page.

Lets say I wanted to hide all the products from a category if I had their ID's in a PHP string like so:

`444,443,145,97,459,460,454,451,450,449,445,446,447,448,457,456,387,385`

Multiply that by like 30, since we have alot of products in that particular category.

Does anyone know how I would do this? Is there something I could add to the category template, or category controller to hide products from showing up on the category page based upon ids.

Comment: you could either add a style if the product id is in the array with css "display:none;" or simply omit it from the results when you are looping the products in the category.tpl, there are many ways to achieve the desired effect but i do not recommend your approach for seo it will create a great deal of trouble later on.... But it is your choice eventually.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonid Bendo remark in its comment you really do have a lot of choices on how to achieve this.

First of all I dont understand why dont you just disable those products, or better, remove them from your category.

I can propose two approachs:

- Database level.
- Controller level.

**Database level**
You can create an extra field bool type in the products that determines the ones you can chose or not and add this condition in the database request:

```
 $sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' |||| AND p.show_cat = '1' |||| GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special";
```

**Controller level**

After getting the list of product, eliminate one by one (not very good technic) the products with the specific id.

There are many other solutions, just depend on how much work and time you want to spend and which quality achieve.